# TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null for CheckBox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```
document.getElementById("cbox0").checked = true;
```

I am using this statement to auto check a checkbox but i get TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null for CheckBox this error. I have tried to use if statement to check if its not a null but it also give me the same error.

```
jsp+='<input id="cbox'+index+'" type="checkbox" name="compare" value="'+rightCard.oid+'" onchange="myFunction('+index+')"><label for="cboxCard'+index+'">&nbsp;</label>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be 2 possible problems.

1. There is no checkbox with the `id` as `cbox0`. Hence, `getElementById` returns `null`, leading to your error
2. Your JavaScript is executed before your checkbox is loaded into the DOM. You can solve this by wrapping your code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener, like this

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("cbox0").checked = true;
});
```

```html
<input id="cbox0" type="checkbox" name="compare" value="test">
```

Note that the snippet above works even without the event listener on StackOverflow. That's probably because StackOverflow's snippet runs it's JavaScript similar to what I've written.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code within an `onload` event.